# Cancel Blender Looking for Missing Textures

Tags: texturing, materials, blend-files, file-format

I have downloaded a blend file from the internet I hope to use in a personal project, everything is pink in the rendered scene (missing textures).

I do not care for the textures, and I do not want to find them, I just want to get rid of the pink (I already have materials I can use). How do I tell blender to stop looking for the damn missing files?

All other searches have led to "just find the missing files", yes I know how to do that, I DO NOT WANT TO DO THAT. I just want to forget about textures, and use the materials.

Comment: Hello :). Well, simply remove the image texture node from your material. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answer. In the materials tab there is no link to any texture nodes, am I missing something? How would I go about removing the textures (the texture tab is empty).

Comment: You need to click the box that says image texture and just get rid of it. It's easier to do in the shader editor window.

Comment: Hey :). If you're not using any image textures, the problem might be somewhere else. Pink color is a general "something failed here" color, it doesn't have to be missing textures.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your responses, I have fixed the problem by unchecking the "use shade nodes to render the world button in the world settings" I've never messed with that before, didn't know it could cause so much trouble.

Comment: Ooooooh, you were missing the HDRI texture, yeah that would definitely make everything everywhere pink

Comment: Thank you guys, the problem is now solved. How do I mark this as solved?...

Comment: I think there should be a big checkmark button or something. Maybe on the answer.

Comment: I need to wait two days before I can accept my own answer, thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your responses, even though the textures on materials were not missing, the world texture (HDRI texture) was found to be missing.

In this case, just go to the world settings and deselect use nodes, of course you can use another one from there if you have it.

Leaving this here in case anyone has the same issue and can't figure out why.